# Android Studio: Can Not Access A Newly Created Folder In Resource

Tags: java, android

I created a folder named raw where I kept a video. Now i have created a function do access the path of the video but my android studio can not find the folder. It's showing error.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Comment: Try Build > Rebuild Project from the Android Studio main menu. If that does not help, confirm that you are importing the correct `R` class.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. @CommonsWare